# Kafka not able to consume without reading from beginning -Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka and trying to build a producer - consumer app using kafka. Here I am able to produce messages to kalka but when I try to consume it back using a consumer, it is returning 0 records.

I check offset for my consumer group, I can see that offset is equals to log length are same (1M in my case - same as number of records).

If I use this config property while creating my consumer, its reading from beginning.

`configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");`

But my requirement is, if I restart consumer, it should start from the previous end point like AMQ.

Is there anything I am missing here. I think offset should change only after a consumer polls. Why is it set to max records length in the beginning itself ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-kafka/5449/consumer-groups-and-offset-management/19390/how-can-i-read-topic-from-its-beginning#t=201703281614275445343

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thank you for your response. But according to the link which you shared, I understand that consumer api wont change offset util I poll and consume from the topic. But it my case offset is being set to end even before I consume any records from the topic. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: That's right. "seeking" to a position is always done lazy. I put a more detailed answer below. Let me know if it helps. Kafka Consumer is a little tricky to understand when you just get started -- it different (and better) than what you can to with other systems. But thus, (in the beginning) also a little harder to get right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the link describes there are couple of scenarios you need to consider:

1. starting a new consumer (new `group.id`): for this case, there will be no committed offset, and thus the consumer start to read according to parameter setting `auto.offset.reset`
2. restarting a consumer (reuse of `group.id`): for this case, the consumer will resume where it left off. Parameter setting `auto.offset.reset` is ignored.

Thus, for scenario (1) you can just "configure" you starting position. For scenario (2), you starting position is "fixed" (ie, always last committed offset) and this cannot be change via a config. However, you can alway do a `.seekToBeginning()` or `.seekToEnd()` before you first call to `poll()` and either read the whole topic or start at the end of the topic. A call to `.seekXX()` will "overwrite" the last committed offset and allow you to start consuming at any offset you like. Note, there is also `seek()` that take on "offset parameter" so you can specify any offset you want to start consuming from.

Comment: I understand how offset works now from your answer and the link which you shared. But what I am not getting is, I produced 1M to a topic using a producer. I created a consumer with unique group id `configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());` . Still this is is consuming any data from the topic without AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG set to earliest.

Comment: In normal case if I start a fresh consumer with new group id, it should start from beginning without I forcefully set offset to beginning right ?

Comment: If you don't set `auto.offset.reset` and use a new consumer (ie, new group ID) it should read from the end... Not sure why it reads the whole topic... (I assume, you don't have any running producer when you start your consumer).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - I have followed this answer. But I am still having problem in reading message after consumer restart. I have posted the details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826279/kafka-0-10-java-consumer-not-reading-message-from-topic . Can you provide me some idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @tuk Not sure. I actually replied on the Kafka user mailing list where you cross posted your question.